# Check for any null values in an object

Tags: c#, null

If I have an object which has other nested objects and properties, like the one below.

```
var request = new GetInfoRequest
{
   GetInformation = new GetInformationType
   {
      Code = "abc",
      Id = "123",
      Item = new InfoItem
      {
         Itemid = "test",
         ItemName = "testname"
      },
      StartDate = new StartdatumType { Start = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1)},
      EndDate = new EndDateType { End = new DateTime.Now }    
   }
};
```

When passing this object to a function I want to check that none of its properties or objects are `null`.

```
public InfoResponse getInfo(request)
{
  // Check that the request object has no null properties or objects.
}
```

Is there a simpler way of checking this than stepping through each child object and property with if statements? A recursive method or something similar?

**Extending**
In my **getInfo** function I don't want to have to write like this:

```
if (request != null && request.GetInformation != null && ... etc.)
```

Comment: Hmm, you can recursively step through each child object and property ... can you elaborate a bit further where you're stuck at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection and iterate through all the properties to check for null. Here is a snippet
to get started

```
using System.Reflection;

GetInfoRequest objGetInfoRequest;
Type getInfoRequestType = objGetInfoRequest.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] myProps = getInfoRequestType.GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.type.getfields%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to iterate through the fields.

you well need some recursion for the nested values.